# Out-of-bag error in Orange

Tags: random-forest, orange

There is some way to see the out-of-bag error in Orange? The widget [Test and Score](https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/evaluate/testandscore/) only reports mean squared error, root mean square, mean absolute error, coefficient of determination and root-mean-square deviation.

Answer (score 0):

Orange3 doesn't calculate the OOB. This must be implemented a separate code. More information about how to calculate the OOB error in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html).